# My PC is not booting. No beep sound, no bios, no hdd indicator blinks

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios, power-supply

I have a PC and I didn't power in it for year or two. Now I want to use it but for some reason it's not working.

I don't hear beep sound while booting, there is no invitation on monitor from bios, it always says signal cable isn't attached. I don't see any hdd activity. But I see that PC is powered on.

What I tried:
* Remove RAM and after it I can hear beeps, seems motherboard is working
* Remove my networking and video cards - no effect
* Change bios battery. I took one which was plugged into my laptop. No effect.

As a result I have powered on PC but bios isn't loaded.

What else can it be? Maybe psu? But why PC powers on? How I can check it if I have only one psu?

Comment: When going through POST, sometimes it can get "stuck" on a device. It may be a device that is tested before the graphics chip - hence it not ever sending display signal.

Comment: Check the jumpers. I once noticed my cmos jumper was missing and i couldn't power on

Comment: I tried booting a laptop without the RAM stick and it did the same thing.Screen is off ,power light on and no beeps

Answer (score 2):

> NOTE: Before making any attempt to remove or replace any part inside
>   the casing, ensure that the power is off.
>
> Well, the first thing that might be causing this is your memory card
>   (RAM). Try to remove it and place it in another memory slot on the
>   motherboard.    If placing the memory card in another slot does not
>   work then the problem lies with the memory card itself. You will need
>   to replace it.
>
> To be sure if your motherboard is still in good working condition,
>   remove the memory card and power on the PC.
>
> You should hear continuous beep sounds.

IF the system beeps i think the PSU is good but if you still insist on checking on it you can visit this [Link](http://www.wikihow.com/Check-a-Power-Supply)

> If you hear this then your motherboard is fine.
>
> You can also attempted to clean the RAM with an eraser.
>
> It could also be that some faulting PCI cards are causing this error.
>
> Try to remove your PCI cards. Normally a faulting PCI modem causes
>   this type of error. Remove it and then power on the pc.
>
> The processor cannot be faulty but still if you want to check it,
>   remove the CPU Cooler fan. Then turn on the PC.
>
> Place your finger on the processor for 2 seconds. You should find the
>   processor heating up. Then turn it off immediately. If this works then
>   your processor is good.  Remember not to leave it ON for more than 5
>   secs.

It can also be the CPU fan. May be the CPU is obviously heating up and
the cooling fan hasn't kicked on yet.Check if the fan is running on
low RPM's.

[Here is the link provided!!](http://ccm.net/forum/affich-27227-computer-powers-on-but-does-not-boot#2)

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell you the solution 100%. As you have not used for long time,  your motherboard, it could be as simple as a bad socket visually inspect for corrosion, scorch marks, bent pins, and foreign objects but note that a microscopic short can cause fatal errors to your computer so you may not be able to see the problem. If you can find nothing wrong in the hardware sector, then try a low-level format utility to wipe your machine and then re-install the bios per http://www.ehow.com/how_4843572_reinstall-bios.html these instructions require you to use a usb flash drive, before you do this though if you can get your hands on another hard drive remove yours and replace with the extra and wait for the problem to happen again, if it doesnt, then go ahead with the reformat.

Answer (score 0):

if your power supply is good, and ram also is good. maybe your bios chip is corrupted try to replace another bios chip and install and update. don't forget to remove the Static current inside in your body before doing or touching some part of your component or elsewhere.

PS. don't try to removed the chip using your finger just use a small flat screw or puller.